# Adding input box value to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to add a date and an integer value from an input box to form a new date. I have applied the following code but this shows the new date formed as `NANANA`. I am attaching my code for this. Can I have inputs and insights over this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#txtDate').datepicker();
});

function getdate() {
var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
var date = new Date(tt);
var newdate = new Date(date);


newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + input);

var dd = newdate.getDate();
var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = newdate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
}    // console.log(someFormattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Date from:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="txtDate" type="text" name="title" maxlength="150" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>New Date formed:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input id="follow_Date" type="text" name="days_for_start" disabled class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Check New Date" />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Extension days:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="extdays" type="text" name="days_for_end" class="form-control" required="" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you are not getting datepicker??? if your adding value in input then you are not getting NANANA

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am getting the datepicker.Then I am filling my input box with an integer that has to be added to the datepicker selected date and form a new date. I am getting NANANA on the new date formed field rather than the new date formed after adding date.

Comment: which datepicker you are using. Add cdn for that in your code

Comment: cdn? I have added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You are not using datepicker cdn. aprt from that i tried it worked for me chek my answer

Comment: added datepicker cdn. check that this will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you don't have any value of input so check input is null then initialize it to 0. Also use parseInt for input. Check this:-[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#txtDate').datepicker();
  });
   $( "#txtDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate:new Date()
    });

function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
    var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
    if (input == "" || input==null)
    {
      input =0
    }
   

var initial = tt.split(/\//).reverse().join('/'); // to change the format

    var date = new Date(initial);
    var newdate = new Date(date);


   newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(input));

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Date from:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input id="txtDate" type="text" name="title" maxlength="150"class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>New Date formed:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input id="follow_Date" type="text" name="days_for_start" disabled class="form-control" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Check New Date" />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="username" class="control-label"><b>Extension days:</b></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="extdays" type="text" name="days_for_end" class="form-control" required="" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But the input value adds up in month rather than the day.

Comment: no its adding in day only but the format is change in input and output @Anand

Comment: Yes I observed. So how can I change both the fields to `d/m/y` format, so that the ambiguity removes.

Comment: i have added jquery ui you can use your own datepicker and can change the date format. In this default format is mm/dd/yy. SO only you are feeling like in month it is getting cgange

Comment: Even I am using jquery datepicker for the date to select. Now how to make get the date as added days and in `d-m-y` format. Sorry I am naïve in jquery so please bear.

Comment: wait i am trying

Comment: just try this  $( "#txtDate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });

Comment: No.. It again got added to `month` part.

Comment: Well what date I am selecting is coming right i.e. `05/02/2018` but when added and the new date turns to be in 'm/d/y' format.

Comment: actually new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");  this take ist thing as month then day. so if you are changing format there it doesn't effect there so pass mm-dd-yy as input format @Anand

Comment: NOthing works. I changed the input date format as well as output date format to `m/d/y`. Still the same

Comment: i have changed the output format and update the code. check now @Anand

Comment: No mate. It did not change at all. Still adding up  in month.

Comment: Something is wrong with the logic I guess. For each time it add up in month. whether its in `d-m-y` or `m-d-y`

Comment: its adding date not month @Anand. try date after 12 . it will add up. Month can't exceed 12 but date can .

Comment: Logic is right @Anand. The only thing is format is m-d-y. in snippet if you are using date 02-23-2018. and in input use 4 it will give you 02-27-2018. which is right output. 23 is the date not month

Comment: I have just added a screenshot of what I am getting. Please take a look. yes result in your code snippet is right. But its not coming up in my website as I posted you the screenshot

Comment: @Anand in your screnshot input date format is m-d-y and output format is d-m-y. i have updated this code in my snippet, Have you run it???????????

Comment: My datepicker is taking up `d-m-y`. I have selected todays date `05/02/2018` I added 13 days to it. and I got `15/5/2018`. Somehow the date and month are swapping places.

Comment: select date 23-02-2017, then check what format you are using @Anand

Comment: `NANANA` on selecting 23-02-2017

Comment: I have used your jquery part but not the html part. Although applied the CDN you have used in html

Comment: just use d-m-y because javascript new date take format m-d-y, if you will pas d-m-y it will take date as month so will get wrong result

Comment: I am using your snippet only Rupal . This does not solves the issue. For datepicker the selected date is in `d-m-y` and the resulting date comes in `m-d-y`. Dont you think this can't be a optimum solution. It will remain always confusing.

Comment: @Anand m using m-d-y in both case. just refresh the page you will get te updated code

Comment: don't know where are u stuck?? added screnshot of my snippet also @Anand

Comment: Yes I checked. No ides. Can there be another way?

Comment: @Anand i have change the format.. now check is this ok for you. input and output both are in d-m-y format

Comment: @Anand this helped or not??

Comment: Sorry Rupal I was away all this time. Let me check.

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Learn More]
regparam.php:31:13
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Learn More]
regparam.php:274:4
TypeError: fakewaffle is undefined
[Learn More] These are the error at console . And the date does not changes. May be its due to file inclusion or something.

Comment: you haven't added jquery and datepicker library. I have done all in my snippet take files from there

Comment: But one more thing, now there are two calendars opening up for date selection.

Comment: might be you have used different library... @Anand

Comment: Yes I will accept for sure. Thanks a lot. Can we connect on email. If you ok with it. and yes now can we remove that extra calendar popping

Comment: just check your library. in my code m getting single calender.. might be you have picked another datepicker

Comment: Sorted. datepicker was being used twice. Thanks again for this effort. I highly appreciate. And yes, if we can connect on email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164602/discussion-between-rupal-and-anand).

Comment: Hi RupaI, I want to disable previous dates from the datepicker . I used `minDate:0` but this does not works. Can you suggest something.

Comment: use minDate:new Date(); @Anand

Comment: Can you depict this in the code above. I have tried this too. Let me check once again.

Comment: @Anand i have updated in above snippet, you can check there

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the onSelect event on datepicker instead of you onclick callback :

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker(
  {
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
      var input = document.getElementById('extdays').value;
      var date = new Date(tt);
      var newdate = new Date(date);

      newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + input);

      var dd = newdate.getDate();
      var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
      var y = newdate.getFullYear();

      var someFormattedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + y;
      document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
    }
  }
);
```

Have a look there : http://jsfiddle.net/x6jfazch/

Comment: The fiddle you posted does not changes the `New Date Formed` field on picking a date and adding the integer value to it. I mean the date is not changed on adding the integer.

Comment: Well in my browser it does (FF 52.) What browser do you use. This date handling stuff can be quite messy around IE

Comment: Well no. Its not working. I picked up a date from datepicker. Then the `New date formed` field fills the picked up date Next I entered 'Extension days' and then on button click the new date does not appears to be changed.